# how to form the nested object in Formdata in javascript

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

how to append the nested object in FormData, my object is

```
{
    name: 'test',
    phone: '454353',
    address: [
        {
            state: 'ewrwer',
            city: 'asdasd'
        }
    ]
}
```

I had append like this

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("name", "test");
data.append("phone", "454353");
data.append("address['state']", "ewrwer");
data.append("address['city']", "asdasd");
```

but this is not working for me when I send this formData in request body the address is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
data.append("address[0]['state']", "ewrwer");
data.append("address[0]['city']", "asdasd");
```

Because, it is inside array of index 0, then inside that you have addresses.

Comment: thanks for your reply is it possible to if the address is not an array just an object how to append . example `address:  { state: 'ewrwer',   city: 'asdasd' }`

Comment: Now, you can use like you did previously. ```data.append("address['state']", "ewrwer");``` ```data.append("address['city']", "asdasd");```

Comment: How is this not working for me. Weird

Comment: Weird, this is not working for me: In backend, I'm just getting fully string instead of json in formData.

```formData.append(`resources[${index}]['type']`, resource.type)```